# How to issue server side Redirect with AJAX error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have the following setup:

1. Web.config has customErrors mode="Off"
2. Global.Application_Error() event calls a custom function called UtilitiesWeb.ProcessError()
3. UtilitiesWeb.ProcessError() logs the error, then redirects the user with: HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(defaultErrorPage, false)

This works well as a good global error handler, except when dealing with AJAX. AJAX displays the error with in JavaScript, and ignores the redirect.

To get the page to redirect on an AJAX error I had to do the following:

1. Update asp:ScriptManager to: <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmanager1" runat="server"
   **OnAsyncPostBackError="ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError"**>
2. Add Server side ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError method that calls UtilitiesWeb.ProcessError()
3. Add the following JavaScript to redirect because AJAX ignores the server side redirect:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> if (typeof (Sys) != 'undefined') {
>    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequest);
>    function endRequest(sender, e) {
>         if (e.get_error()) {
>            window.location = "ErrorPage.aspx"
>         }
>     }
>  }
>  </script>
> ```

But all this seems like a workaround. Is there way to have a server side redirect that works with AJAX errors?

For completeness, here is the code for UtilitiesWeb.ProcessError():

```
public static void ProcessError()
{
    string defaultErrorPage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultErrorPage"];
    string displayError = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DisplayError"];
    Exception ex;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(displayError))
        displayError = displayError.ToLower();

    ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();

    if (ex != null)
        Log.LogException(DateTime.Now, null, ex);

    // Redirect to Default Error page on error
    if (displayError == "basic")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError(); // needed for redirect to work

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(defaultErrorPage))
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(defaultErrorPage, false); // doesn't work with AJAX calls
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and what I ended up doing was returning the url that I wanted it to redirect to and did the same thing as you are doing by setting the `window.location` equal to it.

Comment: While debugging it will get to the redirect line, but something prevents it from redirecting. Odd that we have to do it from the client.

Comment: As far as I know, it is the client that prevents it from redirecting. As Response.Redirect just issues a 302 to the client which then redirects. With ajax, your ajax response should have a 302 and the url to redirect to. In short all 302s are sent back to the client, but with ajax you need to interpret it yourself.

Comment: Should the I look for a 302 in the response instead of an error in the client side code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're making an AJAX request, you just get a response containing some kind of data, which is interpreted by scripts on the client side.

So, in case on error, the only thing that the server can do is send the error in the response to the ajax request.

At this moment, the client-side script receives the error information and you can use it the way you like. You're doing it the right way.

However, if you need to take some extra actions, like logging the error, you have two options:

1) send the error back to the server from the javascript: for example you could use aregular form with an input of type hidden, set the input value, and post the form using form.submti() to your error page. Your page can recover the contents of the hidden field using the Page's Request object and process it.

2) catch the error on server side, within try/catch, or page_error or application_error events, log the exception, or whatever you want to do with it, and throw a new exception that will arrive at the client side, hiding the original exception info.

The second option is cleaner and safer, as you don't send error information to the browser.

Think that the server can't redirect the browser in any way because when the server is sending a reponse to an AJAX request the server isn't rendering a new page for the browser,and the browser is not receiving a new whole page. The server is simply sending  some information to be processed by client-side scripts. So your script is responsible for reloading a new page or whatever you need to do.

Comment: Once you have received the error in client side, now sending the error back to server means you are doing postback. which means control will not move in catch block now. Right?

Comment: Of course. In option 1 you simply send back to the server the exception description that the server sent to the client. In the server side you can do little but logging that text. In option 2 you capture the error in a try catch, or in the page or app error event. In this case you have access to the original Exception. You can throw a new exception which hides the original one. This way, the error message in the client side will be what you want it to be. Anyway, you'll have to deal with the error on client side. Depending on the error, submit the form, or simply show a message to the user.

Comment: can you please share sample link that triggers the app error event in global file once i get the exception in ajax async postback.

Comment: No. That can't be done. You capture the error in global.asax Application Error event (or page error or try catch). But, this happens before the answer is sent to the client. You can "pre-process" the error server side, but can't avoid sending it to the client unless you can correct the error on server side (i.e. retrying the operation an being succesful). If an update panel is involved, you can do nothing else, because you don't have control over the scripts involved in client side.

Comment: ok. Now I feel personally that OP is already doing right job. Correct ?

Comment: Of course, he is doing the right job on client side, but I'm explaining clearly why, and what he can do on the server side to improve it. He felt perhaps there was a better option. Know he should know this is the only option, and also know why.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not a hack. You have implemented the right code.